# How do i multiply every number in the array from position tabProsent[I] to the left?

Tags: javascript

How do i multiply every number in the array from position `tabProsent[I]` to the left? It is not working for me to write  `tabProsent[i].reduceRight(getSum)`.

```js
function getSum(total, num) {
  return total * num;
}

// Update the current slider year (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < tabAar.length; i++) { 
    if (slider.value == tabAar[i]) {
      output2.innerHTML=Math.round(startVerdi * tabProsent[i].reduceRight(getSum));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and your tabProsent[I] is 3 than your otput should be [0,1,2,6,12,20,30]. Is that right?

Comment: it's unclear what's the value of tabProsent

Comment: if I have an array=[1,2,3,4,5] I want to multiply every number from the array from for example array[3] to the left tab[0]. and the output will be 4*3*2*1=24 @Sascha

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution.
**Note:** I don't know what the result should be if the index is negative, actually then you get an result of 1. If index is greater then array-length the I reduce pos to the array-length.

```js
function getMult(arr, pos) {
  if (pos>=arr.length)
      pos = arr.length-1;
  let res =1;
  for (let i=0; i<= pos; i++) {
      res *= arr[i];
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getMult([1,2,3,4,5], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach could look like this:

```js
let multToLeft = (arr, num, m) => {
  
  if (num < 0 || num > arr.length) throw new Error(`Invalid num ${num}`);
  return [ ...arr.slice(0, num).map(v => v * m), ...arr.slice(num) ];
  
};

let examples = [
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 2, 10 ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 3, 20 ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 5, 11 ]
];

for (let [ arr, num, m ] of examples) {
  console.log(`multToLeft(${JSON.stringify(arr)}, ${num}, ${m}) -> ${JSON.stringify(multToLeft(arr, num, m))}`);
}
```

Note that I am working with `num` instead of `index`. I've chosen `num` to indicate the actual *number of elements to the left of the array that get multiplied*. This makes more sense than working with `index`, as it becomes messy to apply the multiplication to zero elements in the array (since supplying `0` would still mean to apply the multiplication to the first array item).